# How to write XML String parameter into NSURLConnection or NSURLSession to call the API?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am creating an XML parameter string to write in NSURLConnection or NSURLSession object but, somehow I'm unable to find any method to write the XML string into the connection object.
Here is the code to generate the XML String.

```
let post = String(format: "<username=\"%@\" RequestType=\"%@\" phonenumber=\"%@\" deviceid=\"%@\"/>", self.txtName.text!, "CreateUser", createString(value: dicUserInfo["mobileNumber"] as AnyObject), (UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!)
```

Can anyone know how to write the above XML string into a connection object?